# How to restrict Laravel login based on role?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm looking for a better, efficient way to restrict user's from logging in to the application based on their based on their given roles. For example only `Users` with the role of `Administrator` can be able to log in to the application dashboard.

This is my implementation

Thanks

Users table
[image: users table]

Users table seeder

```
<?php

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $user = new User();
        $user->name = "admin";
        $user->email = "";
        $user->mobile = "";
        $user->is_admin = true;
        $user->password = bcrypt("");
        $user->active = false;
        $user->save();
    }
}
```

**login Method**

```
  public function login(Request $request)
    {
        // Check validation
        $validator = $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required | email',
            'password' => 'required | string | min:8',
        ]);

        if ($this->authenticate($request)) {
            return redirect()->route('home');
        }

        return redirect('/')->withErrors($validator, 'login');
    }
```

**authenticate Method**

```
    public function authenticate($request)
    {
        return \Auth::guard()->attempt([
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => $request->password,
        ],
            $request->filled('remember')
        );
    }
```

Comment: Are you using the `role` column or the `is_admin` column? You mention `role` but seem to use `is_admin`.

Comment: Please can you explain the error of the code you posted, what does not work? AFAIR this is the code generated by laravel with none added.

Comment: @Script47 I'm using is_admin column.

Answer (score 1):

In your login controller override this method to restrict login

```
protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    return array_merge($request->only($this->username(), 'password'), ['is_admin' => 1]);
}

/**
 * Get the failed login response instance.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
 */
protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    $errors = [$this->username() => trans('auth.failed')];

    // Load user from database
    $user = User::where($this->username(), $request->{$this->username()})->first();

    // Check if user was successfully loaded, that the password matches
    // and is_admin not 1. If so, override the default error message.
    if ($user && \Hash::check($request->password, $user->password) && $user->is_admin != 1) {
        $errors = [$this->username() => "You don't have access to login this system"];
    }

    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json($errors, 422);
    }
    return redirect()->back()
        ->withInput($request->only($this->username(), 'remember'))
        ->withErrors($errors);
}
```

Make sure to use it at top.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
```

Comment: I'd actually override `authenticated` instead because there you'd actually have the user that has signed in.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to deal with such kind of situation is to create your own login function and in this function put a check like:

```
// If the email is registered with a certain role then only allow them further to the login process otherwise return with a proper message

$user = User::where(['email' => $your_email]);
if( $user->role == 'admin' || $user->role == 'agent' ){
  // Login mechanism
}
else{
  // return redirect with a proper message
}
```

and for all further routes create a custom `middleware` to check the same and pass it in routes `middleware` array.